# JavaCV applet does not shows video in web browser, only in desktop

Tags: java, applet, javacv

I have an web application which connect with a security by javaCV. My applet Works perfectly when I execute in the desktop. However, when I integrate this in my JSF page, there are no errors, but the instance of OpenCVFrameGrabber does not start. why?
Below is how I call the Applet in the web page (all dependencies are already in the jar):

```
<applet code="com.br.spacnet.camera.CameraApplet" archive="CameraApplet.jar" width="1000" height="1000"/>
```

Below is the source code of the applet (here I'm using local camera connection for test purposes):

```java
try {

    OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
    jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; instanciou o grabber");
    //grabber.setFormat("mjpeg");
    grabber.start();
    jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; iniciou o Grab");
    opencv_core.IplImage frame = grabber.grab();

    while (jPanel1.isVisible()) {
        jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; entrou no laço");

        jPanel1.getGraphics().drawImage(frame.getBufferedImage(), 0, 0, 320, 240, null);
        jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; redesenhou painel");

    }
    grabber.stop();
    jLabel1.setText(jLabel1.getText() + "; parou o grabber");
    System.exit(0);
} catch (Exception ex) {

    jLabel1.setText("Erro " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Because your JSF page runs in the context of a `SecurityManager`. See also the [Security Manager How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html).

Comment: Thank you, Elliot Frisch. I'm using GlassFish. I checked and the security Manager is disabled by default. However, my problem persists.

Comment: Calling `System.exit()` in a JSF (**or** an Applet) seems like a really poor idea to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  That is why the applet security manager will not allow it, even for a fully trusted applet.  OP - I think you are looking at the wrong security settings and wrong console.  The [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) it the one we need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Andrew Thompson! I enabled my Java Console and I could see several security bloks of JRE. So, I added the following lines to the java.policy, and it worked fine:

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.bytedeco.javacpp.loadlibraries", "read";

permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.bytedeco.javacpp.platform", "read";

permission java.security.AllPermission;

permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks";